# Sending POST request on a wordpress page

Tags: php

When I try to send a post request on a page using WP_Remote_post, I get an HTTP 500 error when I redirect to the page through the form.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Error 500 on wp_remote is generic error, if you can add more information; the problem could also be a return. Best regards,

Comment: Can you check the WordPress debug log (if enabled) and server error log (or PHP error log if separate)? There should be more information in there, including a stack trace, that will give us more information. Please edit it into your question if you find one. Thanks!